# Social login for mobile app to use django-all-auth

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, registration, django-rest-auth

I am learning django and almost completed developing a website, and i used django-allauth for the social login and registration purposes. Now I am trying to develop an app and implemented some part of api using DRF, and for the login, signup, authentication from the app I found django-rest-auth would do the work, and able to signup, login, logout etc... but I don't know how to social login from app and save the details in already existing db.

Any suggestions or references to the process?

Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

Use this links for social login [django allauth as endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861846/plug-in-django-allauth-as-endpoint-in-django-rest-framework/32607462#32607462) and [integration for 3rd party REST/JSON APIs](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/360). This library provide social auth login functionality [django-rest-framework-social-oauth2](https://github.com/PhilipGarnero/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2).